# Mysql for loop repeats same results - can I add unique Id to query before passing?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query generator. In it, I put something like (using UNION)

```
SELECT 
    YEAR('2017-01-01') AS Year,
    MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(1, '%m')) AS Month,
    name,
    MIN(value) AS min,
    MAX(value) AS max,
    TRUNCATE(MAX(value) - MIN(value),
        2) AS cumulative
FROM
    values
        JOIN
    inputs ON id = values.id
WHERE
    values.time >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
        AND values.time <= '2017-01-30 23:59:59'
HAVING (MAX(value) - MIN(feed_value)) >= 0
```

I then loop through the result in the normal way:

```
     <th>Year</th>
                    <th>Month</th>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Minimum</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Maximum</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Difference</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($results as $result) : ?>
                <?php 
                    $total += $result->cumulative;
                ?>
                <tr>
```

This works fine, it creates one table, with all the results in the set displayed. 
What I want to do is, make a second table, and a third, so I can display multiple tables on a page, from multiple UNION selects, up to 20 probably.

If I just duplicate the HTML and PHP, it iterates the same thing over and over

How can I do this so I can duplicate the tables, and each duplicated FOR loop shows the "next" set?

The result I am after is something like

Table 1
values.id 1, Jan to March

Table 2
values.id 2, March to Jun

Right now I get the first one twice. But I know why. Just not how to improve it.

Am I approaching this correctly in thinking the query can somehow carry a way to differentiate?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I had understood everything correctly this could help. Because I haven't programmed in php for a while I use pseudocode for my answer.

Whats following is pseudocode.

### Soltion 1

```
foreach $result
    if $results Jan to March
        $new_results_jm += $results
    end
    if $results March to Jun
        $new_results_mj += $results
    end
end

//table head
foreach $new_results_jm
    //table body
end

//table head
foreach $new_results_mj
    //table body
end
```

Or you can try something, such as:

### Solution 2

```
def get_table_head()
    //create table head
    return $table_head
end

def get_table_body($results)
    //create table body with $results
    return $table_body
end

def get_result(...)
    //your SELECT
    return $result
end

def main()
    //Jan to March
    $result = get_result(...)
    get_table_head()
    get_table_body($result)

    //March to Jun
    $result1 = get_result(...)
    $result2 = get_result(...)
    get_table_head()
    get_table_body($result1)
    get_table_body($result2)
end
```

### Other solution for main

```
def main()
    foreach time_range
        $results[i] = get_result(...)
    end

    foreach $results
        get_table_head()
        get_table_body($results[i])
    end
end
```

I hope I was able to help you.